# How to remove "api/" prefix from custom web route in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I modified my `RouteServiceProvider.php` with this code:

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            // ...

            if (env('THEME_NAME') !== null) {
                try {
                    Route::prefix('api')
                        ->middleware('api')
                        ->namespace($this->namespace)
                        ->group(base_path('routes/client-specific/' . env('THEME_NAME') . '/api.php'));
                } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                    // ...
                }

                try {
                    Route::middleware('web')
                        ->namespace($this->namespace)
                        ->group(base_path('routes/client-specific/' . env('THEME_NAME') . '/web.php'));
                } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Then in `routes/client-specific/' . env('THEME_NAME') . '/web.php` file I wrote this code:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('{local}/cs/list', [ClientSpecific\CustomController::class, 'listPublic']);
```

Then I make a `php artisan route:list` and I get this route in the list:

```
api/{local}/cs/list
```

In the RouteServiceProvider I use the `web` middleware for this route file.

Why put Laraver the `api/` prefix to my route? And how can I remove it?

Thanks!

**=== UPDATE ===**

I added a more detailed code, started on `Route::prefix('api')` line.

Answer (score 0):

So it’s looks like $this->namespace is “api”. And by the way, you don’t want to use env() outside config files.

Comment: I removed `->namespace($this->namespace)` part from the code, but same result

Comment: Check your api.php file this sounds like you didn’t saved file or you editing wrong file.

Comment: I saved the file :)

Comment: So what is api.php content?

Comment: There are many routes defined, but none of these things. This code is exists only in web.php

Comment: I updated the code. This is much more detailed.

Comment: Only explanation is $this->namespace where this property defined what value it has? dd($this->namespace) or show it